DeprecationWarning: Calling start() is no longer necessary. It can be safely omitted
I cannot resolve the issue in NestJS microservices.
(node:6600) DeprecationWarning: Calling start() is no longer necessary. It can be safely omitted.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created) 

is being printed to the console. How can I get rid of this message.
Here is my main.ts file:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { USERS_PACKAGE_NAME } from '@globals/interfaces/users.proto';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
      AppModule,
      {
        transport: Transport.GRPC,
        options: {
          url: 'localhost:50050',
          package: USERS_PACKAGE_NAME,
          protoPath: resolve(__dirname, '../../globals/protos/users.proto'),
        },
      },
    );
    await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();

Packages I'm using:
@grpc/grpc-js: ^1.10.7
@nestjs/microservices: ^10.3.8
nest: 10.3.0
node: v20.11.0

I have tried to use app.init() instead of app.listen(). But with app.init() server does not accept any request or connection.
